# Chain of different Docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have to analyze tons of files which require different tools. Right now I have several steps which each are in their own seperate Docker container. Each container takes a folder as an input and provides a folder with output files, everything is working fine. Now I want to automate this as a chain of these containers. How can one container start the next one though? Do I have to use Docker in Docker as a container can not start a new one in the host system ?

Bonus:

- what if the run command differs, as it depends on the output of the
  previous container ?

Thank you so much, couldn't find a working solution yet.

Comment: Just use docker-compose to start multiple containers. You can also use a shellscript to do that. Or is the requirement that the second container only starts when the first is done?

Comment: @Hannes yes, as it requires the output of the first one.

Comment: Maybe it is better to use a Multi Stage docker build...with this you can share the data and chain it with each other: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: @Hannes I want to use a flask website as a GUI to start the analysis. If I would go for the multistage-build, the website wouldn't work anymore, is that correct ? Also can I set the shared volumes for the next container dynamically with this solution?

Comment: @TheInovat , are you looking for something like:
Docker in Docker in Docker in Docker ......?

Comment: @Ashwani Not really. Perfect would be a main container, that is able to start a chain of containers, which analyze my data.

Comment: @TheInovat why are you calling it a "chain", you should call it a list of container.

Comment: @Ashwani A list of containers then. The containers just have to subsequently start the next one when they terminate.

Comment: Do you have some code samples please.  Even one of the Dockerfiles and the run command?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simple start the containers after each other you can to it with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running first container"                                                                                                                                                                                 
docker run -it --name sleep1 --rm sleep
echo "Running second container"
docker run -it --name sleep2 --rm sleep
```

Example Dockerfile (docker build -t sleep .):

```
FROM alpine:3.3
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/ash", "-c", "sleep 5"]
```

Maybe this help you to get what you want. If not please describe a bit more what you want to achieve. Maybe with code examples or something.

Edit:
Based on the new informations of the creator i see only two possibilities to chain the start of mulitple containers from out of a container:

- 1.: Run Docker in Docker (nested containers). But this is not really recommended.
- 2.: Run the script from above via ssh from the container on the host machine.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for taking your time to help me.
Your solution definitely does work, but I want it to be a little different. Perfect would be a main container, that is able to start a chain of container, where the containers subsequently start the next one when it terminates. I hope thats a little more clear ?

Comment: I see only two possibilities: 1.: Run Docker in Docker (nested containers). But this is not really recommended. 2.: Run the script from above via ssh from the container on the host machine.